# How can I use STM32F303's pins as analog outputs?

Tags: analog, stm32, dac

I am designing a custom STM32F303-based PCB and need to get several analog outputs from the microcontroller. STM32 has two DAC channels which I suppose I can use for this purpose to avoid getting PWM pseudo-analog signals, but rather the analog ones. If I need more of those outputs, should I also include external DACs between MCU and the final outputs?

Comment: What you should do depends on what are your requirements for the analog outputs so it's impossible to say how the requirements could be met.

Comment: Are these analog outputs static? Or are they dynamic? If static you can use digital pots.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should add external chips via SPI or I2C as you stated yourself; you don't want a pseudo-analog PWM signal and you want more than two outputs.

I've found [one at Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4470) which has four channels.

Comment: Thanks! And as for the digital outputs, it is not really necessary to add ADC between the STM32 and the outputs, right?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you want an analog output created from a digital signal you'll need to pass this "pattern" via the I2C layer to the external IC. You might choose the option to feed back the signal to the controller (ADC ) in order to check and correct it. But this depends on the application.

Comment: What about other solutions than adding DACs? Why do you suggest adding DACs if you don't know why they are needed?

Comment: I answered a question with a limited scope. I presume the OP knows what a DAC is and why he wants them, because this would yielded a different question otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to another answer, you don't necessarily need to add more DAC chips.

Depending on your needs, you can simply demultiplex the MCU DAC outputs into sample/hold circuits to have more analog outputs.